# Facebook Login with MVVM pattern

Tags: swift, mvvm

I'm trying to learn `MVVM` and it's kind of hard to me to migrate from `MVC` to `MVVM`
I'm working with Facebook Login. Here's what I'm setup my code :

Inside `ViewController` :

```
fileprivate func facebookLoginAction(){
    self.viewModel.performFacebookLogin(rootVC: self)
}
```

Inside `ViewModel` :

```
func performFacebookLogin(rootVC: UIViewController) {
    let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: rootVC) { [weak self] (result, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let result = result else {return}
        if result.isCancelled {
            return
        }
        if (result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
            self?.getFacebookUserData()
        }
    }
}
```

It's works but I'm not sure that I'm doing right `MVVM` pattern because I'm passing `ViewController` to `ViewModel`.
Can you give me some ideas or rules of `MVVM`

Comment: I'm not sure it's right or wrong but if you don't want to pass `ViewController` to `ViewModel`, you can ignore it and use `nil` for `fromViewController`. In this case, the method will find the topmost view controller itself and use. Take a look at Facebook document for this method for more detail https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've done a pretty good job of implementing MVVM here! The general rule of MVVM is that if you were to strip out all of the "visuals" from your view controller, it would look identical to your view model (ie: the view model holds all of the information). Unfortunately the API here makes it difficult to avoid passing the view controller to its model directly. One possible option is to have the view model implement a view model delegate protocol...

`protocol viewModelDelegate {
   func getViewController() -> viewController
}`

The view Controller should implement this protocol and return self. Then, you can get your view controller by calling `delegate?.getViewController()`.

Honestly, this kind of abuses the delegate pattern, and technically still passes the view controller TYPE to the view model haha, so this might not be the best option for you!